# How do you find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, alternating-expression

Extra information which may be useful is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (Euler's solution to the Basel Problem).

Comment: Hint: What can you say about $\sum 1/(2n)^2$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114667.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Is there anything else you can give me here? What about the alternating signs- where did those go?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate  $\int_0^1 {\ln(1+x)\over x}\,dx$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114664/evaluate-int-01-ln1x-over-x-dx)

Answer (score 1):

(Evaluating the sum without using the extra information) We will express the sum

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align*}

via a complex contour integral. It employs the fact that the function

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\sin \pi z}
\end{align*}

has simple poles at all integers $n$, as we now verify:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{\sin \pi z} & = \dfrac{1}{\sin \pi [n + (z-n)]}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{1}{(-1)^n [\pi (z-n) - \frac{1}{3!} \pi^3 (z-n)^3 + \cdots]}
\nonumber \\
& = (-1)^n \dfrac{1}{(z-n) \pi [1 - \frac{1}{3!} \pi^2 (z-n)^2 + \cdots]}
\nonumber \\
& = (-1)^n \dfrac{1}{(z-n) \pi} [1 + \frac{1}{3!} \pi^2 (z-n)^2 + \cdots]
\nonumber \\
& = (-1)^n \dfrac{1}{(z-n) \pi} + \cdots
\end{align*}

This allows us to write

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} = -\frac{1}{2 i} \oint_C \dfrac{1}{z^2 \sin \pi z} dz
\end{align*}

where the contour $C$ is defined in fig (a).

[image]

We have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^2}
= - \frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{C+C'} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \sin \pi z} dz
\end{align*}

where the contour $C'$ is defined in fig (a). We complete the path of integration along semicircles at infinity (see fig (b)) since the integration along them vanishes. Since the resulting enclosed area contains no singularities except at $z=0$, we can shrink this contour down to an infinitesimal circle $C_0$ around the origin (see fig (c)). So that

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} = - \frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{C_0} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \sin \pi z} dz
\end{align}

Expanding the integrand around $z=0$ and isolate the $z^{-1}$ term to obtain the residue. Then

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{z^2 \sin \pi z} = \dfrac{1}{z^2 (\pi z - \frac{1}{3!} \pi^3 z^3 + \cdots)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
= \dfrac{1}{z^3 \pi (1 - \frac{1}{6} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
= \dfrac{1}{z^3 \pi} (1 + \frac{1}{6} \pi^2 z^2 + \cdots)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
= \cdots + \dfrac{\pi}{6} \frac{1}{z} + \cdots
\end{align}

So that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n^2} = -\frac{1}{4 i} \oint_{
C_0} \dfrac{1}{z^2 \sin \pi z} dz
= -\frac{1}{4 i} (-2 \pi i) (\dfrac{\pi}{6})
= \frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align*}

Comment: I think it should be $\pi^2/12$.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the mistake.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.  Besides, [it was a megaduplicate](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let
$s(m)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^m}
$.
(Yours is $m=2$.)

Then

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^m}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^m}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n)^m}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^m}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n)^m}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n)^m}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^m}-\dfrac1{2^{m-1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^m}\\
&=(1-\dfrac1{2^{m-1}})\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^m}\\
&=(1-\dfrac1{2^{m-1}})\zeta(m)\\
\end{array}
$

Yours is the case
$m=2$
so the result is
$(1-\dfrac1{2})\zeta(2)
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}
$.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.  Besides, [it was a megaduplicate](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score -1):

$A = \sum\frac{1}{n^2} = [odd+even] = \sum \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(2n)^2}$.
$S = \sum(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^2} = [odd-even]=\sum \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = A-2\sum \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = A - \frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n^2} = A/2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6\cdot 2}.$

A simpler way of stating this is $S = odd-even=odd+even-2even = A - \frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n^2} = A/2.$

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. Besides, [it was a megaduplicate](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: These types of comments really ruin this community.

Comment: Duplicating answers to [such (multi)duplicate questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186127) pollutes this site.

Comment: @Hunaphu on the contrary